# Django query User growth by month

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Is there a way to get a `User` count() based on the `date_joined` grouped by year/month using Django ORM?

I was able to get this data using raw SQL on my Django/Postgres project like this:

```
from django.db import connection
...    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT
            to_char(date_joined, 'YYYY/MM') as month,
            cast(count(id) as int) as total
        FROM users_user
        GROUP BY month 
        ORDER BY month DESC
        ''')
```

That returns me a list as:
`[('2015/12', 105), ('2016/01' , 78), ('2016/02', 95)...]`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.all() \
        .extra({'created': "to_char(date_joined, 'YYYY/MM')"}) \
        .values('created') \
        .annotate(created_count=Count('id')) \
        .order_by('-created')
```

Comment: If you use `\\` for line continuation it will break if you have trailing whitespace. Use parentheses instead.

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.10+ you can use the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth


User.objects.all() \
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth("date_joined")) \
    .values("month") \
    .annotate(c=Count("id")) \
    .order_by("-month")
```

Under the hood, the answer given by [ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36851268/9714115) will translate to the following SQL:

```
SELECT ( To_char(date_joined, 'YYYY/MM') ) AS "created", 
       Count("users_user"."id")            AS "created_count" 
FROM   "users_user" 
GROUP  BY ( To_char(date_joined, 'YYYY/MM') ) 
ORDER  BY "created" DESC
```

The 'newer' method will run the following SQL:

```
SELECT Date_trunc('month', "users_user"."date_joined" at time zone 
                           'Europe/London') AS 
       "month", 
       Count("users_user"."id") 
       AS "c" 
FROM   "users_user" 
GROUP  BY Date_trunc('month', "users_user"."date_joined" at time zone 
                              'Europe/London') 
ORDER  BY "month" DESC
```

But that's largely irrelevant - what about performance?

```
4,000 users:
    Method 1: 0.003886s
    Method 2: 0.005572s

50,000 users:
    Method 1: 0.064483s
    Method 2: 0.040544s
```

Marginal differences, but depends on your use case/scale...